# xclip the output from head and tail

Tags: copy-and-paste

I  intent to copy the output from ls

```
gaowei@alpha:~/Downloads$ ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5
Abraham Silberschatz, Greg Gagne, Peter B. Galvin - Operating System Concepts (2018, Wiley).pdf
Alan Shalloway - Design Patterns Explained_ A New Perspective on Object-Oriented Design (2004, Addison-Wesley Professional).pdf
Alan Shalloway, James R. Trott - Design patterns explained a new perspective on object-oriented design (2004, Addison-Wesley Professional).chm
Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey D. Ullman - Compilers - Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2006, Pearson_Addison Wesley).pdf
Anany Levitin - Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms (2012, Pearson).pdf
```

and tried

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5 | xargs xclip -sel clip
xclip: Abraham: No such file or directory
me@host:~/Downloads$ xclip -sel clip $(ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5)
xclip: Abraham: No such file or directory
```

They failed. Should I have to redirect the output to a file before employ 'xclip'?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the file *names* or the files' *contents* to the clipboard?

Comment: copy the file names @steeldriver

Comment: in that case, remove the `xargs`

Comment: thank you, could you please transmit it to the answer. @steeldriver

Comment: Done - see below :)

Comment: Please remind me to update my answer, maybe like next week on Saturday/Sunday

Comment: roger it @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the file*names* from your pipe to `xclip`, all you need is

```
ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5 | xclip -sel clip
```

because `xclip` by default reads text from standard input.

---

By adding `xargs`, you were passing the output of the pipe as a sequence of filename *arguments* to `xclip`, which in principle would be the way to copy the files' *contents* to the clipboard, however it was failing because by default `xargs` considers each whitespace-delimited word as a separate argument - if you **did** want to copy file contents to the clipboard, the way around that would be to tell `xargs` to use a newline delimiter:

```
ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5 | xargs -d '\n' xclip -sel clip
```

or, even better (since newline is actually a legal - albeit rarely used - character in filenames), make the whole pipeline null-delimited:

```
printf '%s\0' * | head -zn 10 | tail -zn 5 | xargs -0 xclip -sel clip
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is use `find` to print filename using `-name` or `-iname` flag. `xclip` takes input via stdin, so all you have to do  is to send the filename via pipe.

```
$ find -maxdepth 1  -type f -name 'Abraham*Operating Systems*pdf'  -printf '%P\n' | xclip -sel clip
```

The `-name`/`-iname` flags use simple pattern matching, and `-printf` with with `%P` format specifier will output just the filename. Note that `find` assumes current working directory `.` if no directory is specified.

---

As for your original command

```
$ ls | head -n 10 | tail -n 5 | xargs xclip -sel clip
```

there's a few problems with it. One is parsing `ls` (reading it's output via command), which is [generally not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The output may contain color control characters and other information. In fact there were [proposals to add an option flag](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-02/msg00005.html) to `ls` so that it can output items separated by `\0` character (this is the safe method), but that has been rejected by GNU developers for obvious reasons:

> However ls is really a tool for direct consumption by a human, and in that case further processing is less useful. For futher processing, find(1) is more suited.

Another problem with your original command is `xargs` usage here. `xclip` can read input from stdin just fine, so if you want to send some text to clipboard, it is easy enough to just do something like `echo foo | xclip -sel clip`. If you want to copy **contents** of a file, then you should make that file stdin

```
xclip -sel clip < /etc/passwd
```

Copying filename in command-line can be problematic because of special characters such as tabs, newlines, spaces. Generally in command-line you'd use `find`. Filemanagers and GUI tools use URI form of filenames, where special characters and UTF-8 symbols are replaced with hex values. For 
example,

```
$ gio info --attributes='uri:'   文er-\ 林中鸟\ -\ 林中鳥-YY神曲-uUX0sZHQMkw.mp3 | awk '/uri:/{print $2}'
file:///home/xie/%E6%96%87er-%20%E6%9E%97%E4%B8%AD%E9%B8%9F%20-%20%E6%9E%97%E4%B8%AD%E9%B3%A5-YY%E7%A5%9E%E6%9B%B2-uUX0sZHQMkw.mp3
```

This can be passed to `xclip` and later pasted into web browser's address bar. Nautilus and File Selection dialogs don't seem to support pasting that from plain-text clipboard though.

#### See also

- [Is there a reason why ls does not have a --zero or -0 option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112126/85039)